# ToString() method doesn't compile

Tags: java, tostring

Not really sure why jGrasp isn't accepting my toString equals method.  Any help would be great, stuck at a stand still.

```
public class Rottweiler extends GuardDog {
    private String color = "Brown";

    public String toString() {
        String returnString = super.toString();
        returnString += String.format(Constant.FORMAT, "Color:", this.color);

        return toString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just look at your toString method.... You don't see anything weird about it?!

Comment: Is it because of the extra `}` character a couple of lines above `toString()`?  I'm not really sure which one matches that, because of your formatting.

Comment: What's a 'tostring equals method'?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to do your job. Please only include relevant code (and text). You knew the problem was in the `toString()` method, there's no need to include constructors, comments, whitespaces, getters or setters. You have to describe the specific issue and only the specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `toString` to `returnString` like this:

```
public String toString() {
    String returnString = super.toString();
    returnString += String.format(Constant.FORMAT, "Color:", this.color);

    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the wrong value in your toString method.

```
public String toString() {
    String returnString = super.toString();
    returnString += String.format(Constant.FORMAT, "Color:", this.color);
    return returnString; //this line is the correct one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `toString()` method you are creating a String-object named `returnString` but you try to return an undefined object `toString`.

```
public String toString() {
    String returnString = ... // <--
    return toString; // <-- should be returnString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `toString()` method -

```
public String toString() {
  String returnString = super.toString();
  returnString += String.format(Constant.FORMAT, "Color:", this.color);
  return toString; // <-- Why toString? You want returnString.
}
```

I normally use a `StringBuilder` in my `toString()` method(s), so it might look like this -

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(super.toString());
  sb.append(String.format(Constant.FORMAT, "Color:", this.color));
  return sb.toString();
}
```